# how to set a text views text to an integer value of an object that was created from another class

Tags: java, android, listview

the title is a bit confusing sorry about that i didnt know how to put it in words properly. I have a listView that uses an Adapter that i created myself. When the first row of the listView is pressed I have made it so it creates a new object from class called Ship that has 3 integer values. Below

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.hangar);

        ListAdapter adapter = new HangarAdapter(this, ship);
            hangarList.setAdapter(adapter);

            hangarList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                   Intent sendListEvents = new Intent();
                    if(position == 0)
                    {
                        Ship ship1 = new Ship();
                        ship1.setAddAmount(50);
                        ship1.setAddTime(5000);
                        ship1.setAddSpend(1000);
                        ship1.shipAdd();
                    }
}
}
```

In my adapter i have a textView called TextView2 and I want to set the text of it to ship1's value called addSpend. How do i do that.

```
    if (position == 0) {
                theImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.planet);
                TextView2.setText("This is where I want ship1's addSpend value to be displayed")
}
```

Comment: You can use your onItemClick() `View view` parameter to find your Button using view.findViewById(R.id.textView2) and modify its text value.

Comment: And? Where is the problem? Have you tried `TextView2.setText(String.valueOf(ship1.getAddSpend()))` already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I am correct then you have in the HangarAdapter class the object `this` (which references to the Activity in which you are right now: `ListAdapter adapter = new HangarAdapter(this, ship);`). Save this object to an variable (I call it MainActivity) in the HangarAdapter class .

Now you could just say in the HangarAdapter class: `MainActivity.findViewById("TextBoxID").setText("MUHAHAHAH")`

Comment: findViewById does not work. it says cannot resolve method. Is this because HangarAdapter is not an activity?